# Latency of digital-to-analog converter (DAC)

Tags: dac

I wonder what is the minimal latency of a digital-to-analog converter (DAC).
What is the minimal clock cycle the DAC takes between the arrival of the digital signal to the output of analog signal?

Comment: It depends on how rich you are. I am a poor hobbyist. My favourite DAC/ADC module is this: https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-pcf8591.html

Comment: And conversion rate is about 10kHz: 
PCF8591 8-bit A/D and D/A converter (I2C, Conversio frequncy ~= 11kHz) - NXP 2013
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCF8591.pdf

Comment: It doesn't have to take any clock cycles at all. If you make the DAC out of a chain of resistors, how could it?

Comment: After the arrival of DAC data, you have a settling time of 90us for the PCF8591. Latency is generally used in systems that "delays" data samples while converting. Latency can also be defined with N samples ... that is to say that the results of the actual conversions will be "delayed" by N samples (example N =1).

Comment: @tlfong01, if budget is unlimited?

Comment: @Rickyim (1) DAC1628D1G25 16-bit 1.25Gsps - NXP
https://www.arrow.com/en/products/dac1628d1g25/nxp-semiconductors， 
(2) Can't Buy Me ADC - Beatles 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srwxJUXPHvE

Answer (score 2):

I used an [AD9742](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9742.pdf) 12-bit DAC in a recent project. No doubt far from the fastest, but fast enough to synthesize some clean low MHz signals when fed fast digital data.

Settling time is ~11ns. Something like $12 in 100's, so not crazy expensive.

When you develop your specific requirements you can do parametric searches at the suppliers such as analog.com, ti.com etc. and distributors and narrow down your search.